# Second chrome.sockets.tcp.send call always results in "500 Invalid command: try being more creative"

Tags: sockets, ftp, google-chrome-app

Building an FTP client as a Chrome app, using chrome.sockets.tcp.

At first, I kept getting "500 Invalid command: try being more creative" any time I tried to send the password. Then I realized that it was returning that error on the second command, no matter what command I was sending.

Ie. USER, followed by PASS, would give me the error.
FEAT, followed by USER, would give me the error.
FEAT, followed by HELP, would give me the error.

I've tried waiting an interval before issuing the second command. to no avail.

```
chrome.app.window.create('index.html', {
  id: "helloWorldID",
    bounds: {
    width: width,
    height: height,
    left: Math.round((screenWidth-width)/2),
    top: Math.round((screenHeight-height)/2)
   }
});


var IP = "server.com";
var PORT = 21;
var ftp_username = "user";
var ftp_password = "password";
var socketID;

function ab2str(buf) {
   return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(buf));
 }
function str2ab(str) {
   var buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length*2); // 2 bytes for each char
   var bufView = new Uint8Array(buf);
   for (var i=0, strLen=str.length; i<strLen; i++) {
     bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
   }
   return buf;
 }

function onCallback( result ){
    console.log( "onCallback", result );    
};

chrome.sockets.tcp.create({ persistent:false }, function(createInfo) {
    socketID = createInfo.socketId;

    chrome.sockets.tcp.connect( socketID, IP, PORT, onCallback);
});

chrome.sockets.tcp.onReceive.addListener(function(info) {
    //console.log( "onReceive", info.socketId );
    var d = ab2str( info.data );
    console.log( d );

    if (d.indexOf("220 ")>-1){

        // send user.
        console.log( "send " + ftp_username);
        chrome.sockets.tcp.send( socketID, str2ab("USER "+ftp_username+"\n"), onCallback );
    }
    if (d.indexOf("331 ")>-1){
        // send password.
        console.log( "send password");
        chrome.sockets.tcp.send( socketID, str2ab("PASS "+ftp_password+"\n"), onCallback );
    }

  });
  chrome.sockets.tcp.onReceiveError.addListener(function(info) {
      console.log( "onReceiveError", info );
  });

});
```

Comment: What is str2ab for? What about passing the string to send() directly?

Comment: str2ab converts the string to an ArrayBuffer, which is what chrome.sockets.tcp.send is expecting as the 2nd param.

Comment: Why are you reserving two bytes per char in the array buffer? Try it with one.

Comment: @Danila that was it! thank you! can you post as an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to reserve 1 byte per character in the ArrayBuffer instead of two

```
var buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length); // 1 byte for each char
```

Answer (score 1):

You might like to end the strings to send using `\r\n` but only `\n`.

From [RFC 959](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc959.txt):

> The File Transfer Protocol follows the specifications of the Telnet
>      protocol for all communications over the control connection.  Since
>      the language used for Telnet communication may be a negotiated
>      option, all references in the next two sections will be to the
>      "Telnet language" and the corresponding "Telnet end-of-line code".
>      Currently, one may take these to mean NVT-ASCII and <CRLF>.  No other
>      specifications of the Telnet protocol will be cited.
>
> FTP commands are "Telnet strings" terminated by the "Telnet end of
>      line code". [...]

Comment: I did try that, thank you.  That was one of my first thoughts. Unfortunately it didn't work.  Same result as using only \n.